# Relationship mapping for one-to-many with existing database, one issue with aggregate convention and one with association table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Two part question,
We have a preexisting database with a structure we want to keep for all existing projects, but want some of the functionality within our API as well, but i can't seem to get it working.

Question 1:
How would i go about mapping a one-to-one relationship between two tables in EF with a structure like this (psudo)

```
class MainEntity{
 long id
 string name
 list<Task> tasks
}

class Task {
 long id
 string name
 long AggregateId
 string AggregateType (database would then be have the value 'MainEntity' in this case)
}
```

Can't seem to set a .Where(x => x.AggregateType == "MainEntity") within the DbSet mapping.
The mapping against aggregate is ment to support our SecondEntity and ThirdEntity as well so the convention needs to stay intact.

Question 2:
How would i go about mapping the following one-to-many relationship with an existing association table ?

```
class Company {
 long id
 string name
 list<employee>
}

class Employee {
 long id
 string name
 ... (employee specific detials)
}
```

DB Tables:

- Companies
- Employees
- Employees2Companies (Containing: CompanyId and EmployeeId)

There are no links between Company and Employee except for in the association table in the database.

Comment: (1) Not supported (2) See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many

Comment: Hmm, guess ill just have to be creative then to get it working

Comment: Made it work with empty setter and shadowcolumn with the defined AggregateType

Comment: The One-To-Many mapping with associationtable was also possible by using an additional class mapped to both sides